# Why do I get a lot of errors while adding Alamofire framework?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I try to add Alamofire framework for IOS using cocoapods and adding it directly to the project. I get a lot of compiler errors in both cases though I follow all the guides.

[image]

Perhaps somebody can help me?

Comment: It seems that you try to compile Swift 2 code with Xcode 6. You'll have to upgrade to Xcode 7 (which is the current version).

Comment: Try add in Podfile:

pod 'Alamofire', '3.0.0-beta.3' after you upgrade to XCode 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Xcode and Alamofire are you using?

I can see an error there for Do-While which was removed in Swift 2.0

I guess you need to Upgrade to Xcode 7. Then follow again the steps from Alamofire Readme Page on Github.

I personally prefer CocoaPod to add frameworks.

Comment: Thank u guys! Yes I upgraded my XCode and everything works fine!